Xdebug not works with VS Code and MAMP
I use PHP debug extension in VS Code. But debugger doesnt see php superglobals at all (like post, get, session...)

While debugging no errors in IDE.
I followed all instructions on Xdebug site: downloaded recomended file and put it in C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\ext.
In C:\MAMP\conf\php8.1.0\php.ini I have:
[xdebug]
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = localhost
xdebug.client_port = 80
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
xdebug.dump.GET = *
xdebug.dump.POST = *
xdebug.dump_globals = true
xdebug.log = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\newlog.log"

In C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\php.ini I have (without following code debugger didnt work at all in IDE):
 [xdebug]
zend_extension = "C:/MAMP/bin/php/php8.1.0/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = localhost
xdebug.client_port = 80
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
xdebug.dump.GET = *
xdebug.dump.POST = *
xdebug.dump_globals = true
xdebug.log = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\newlog.log"

I have tried configurations without xdebug.dump - the same result.
In settings.json of VS Code:
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\MAMP\\bin\\php\\php8.1.0\\php.exe",
    "phpserver.phpPath": "C:\\MAMP\\bin\\php\\php8.1.0\\php.exe",
    "phpserver.browser": "msedge",
    "php.debug.executablePath": "C:\\MAMP\\bin\\php\\php8.1.0\\php.exe"

Launch.json for PHP debugger extension in IDE I didnt edit.
For debugging, I select "Launch currently open script" configuraion.
I had notifications about validation of php.validate.executablePath (tried edit different ways), but debugger launches in IDE without error in build-in terminal.
OS Windows 10. Local server MAMP

Solved issue:

Must not write in file C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\php.ini
port in php.ini must be the same as in launch.json (section Listen for XDebug)
content of C:\MAMP\conf\php8.1.0\php.ini must be following:


zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = localhost
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
xdebug.log = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\newlog.log"


